# How to extract values of one dataframe from another dataframe having same columns in r?

Tags: r

How to Get values of columns from df2 to df1 having matching df1 dates

```
 df1 <- data.frame(a= seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-08-14"), to = as.Date("2021-08- 20")
         , by = 1),
          vv= NA,
          tv= NA)

 df2 <- data.frame(a=as.Date(c("2021-08-14","2021-08-15","2021-08-22",
                            "2021-08-16","2021-08-17","2021-08-25","2021-08-26")),
                vv=c(12,11,13,14,15,16,10),
                tv= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

**Required Output**

```r
df3 <- data.frame(
  a = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-08-14"), to = as.Date("2021-08-19"), by = 1),
  vv = c(12, 11, 14,15, NA,NA),
  tv = c(1,2,4,5,NA, NA)
  )
```

Comment: I took the freedom to edit your required output, so it can be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rows_update`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  rows_patch(semi_join(df2, df1, by = "a"))
```

returns

```r
           a vv tv
1 2021-08-14 12  1
2 2021-08-15 11  2
3 2021-08-16 14  4
4 2021-08-17 15  5
5 2021-08-18 NA NA
6 2021-08-19 NA NA
7 2021-08-20 NA NA
```

Comment: Actually a silly one, but I thought it to be funny. :D

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your data samples at first, changed a little bit (deleted a row because of a typo)

```
df1= data.frame(a= seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-08-14"), to = as.Date("2021-08- 20"), by = 1),
          vv= NA,
          tv= NA)

df2= data.frame(a=as.Date(c("2021-08-14","2021-08-15","2021-08-22",
                            "2021-08-16","2021-08-17","2021-08-25","2021-08-26")),
                vv=c(12,11,13,14,15,16,10),
                tv= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))

df1$vv <- NULL
df1$tv <- NULL

df4 <- merge(df1,df2,by = 'a',all.x=T)
```

**output ;**

```
  a             vv    tv
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-08-14    12     1
2 2021-08-15    11     2
3 2021-08-16    14     4
4 2021-08-17    15     5
5 2021-08-18    NA    NA
6 2021-08-19    NA    NA
7 2021-08-20    NA    NA
```

Comment: can't assign NULL to columns manually, as i have 5000 + columns in df1

Answer (score 1):

We could do a `left_join` and remove the columns not wanted with `select(-c(vv.x, tv.x))`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by="a") %>% 
    select(-c(vv.x, tv.x), vv=vv.y, tv=tv.y)
```

```
           a vv tv
1 2021-08-14 12  1
2 2021-08-15 11  2
3 2021-08-16 14  4
4 2021-08-17 15  5
5 2021-08-18 NA NA
6 2021-08-19 NA NA
7 2021-08-20 NA NA
```

Comment: can't use select  columns manually, as I have 5000 + columns in df1